# How to log results to console with MongoDB 3.0 c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver

I am writing the simple c# console program to connect mongodb db instance and get the value from the mongodb and need to display console window.  I am using mongodb version 3.0.

I am getting date but not able display console.  I am getting struck with syntax.

Any one please help me, I have shared my sample code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
namespace MongoCHash
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mongod = new MongoClient();
            var db=mongod.GetDatabase("MyDB");
            var movies = db.GetCollection<Movie>("movie");


        }
    }

    public class Movie
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "I am getting date" but I don't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry its typo error.  I mean "I am getting data"

Comment: Ok, please edit your question to fix the typo. Is this all your code? You need to be calling `movies.Find` to actually query the collection and get the docs. See the [quick tour docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You have got a Movie object collection you need to iterate over the collection and the do a Console.Log() of what ever property of the movie object you want including date. If you want I can post an example.